# Is it possible to programmatically access Download folder on Android Q (SDK >= 29)?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-storage

I want to list all files `.txt` in the **Download** folder and then allow the user to pick one and read its content. My `minSdkVersion` is `16`, but I came across this problem because my Android is Q (29).

**What I tried:**

Apparently `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` would solve it for SDK <= 29. However, I didn't test it because I would first like to check out a solution for Android Q.

[getExternalStoragePublicDirectory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) says:

> When an app targets Build.VERSION_CODES.Q, the path returned from this method is no longer directly accessible to apps. Apps can continue to access content stored on shared/external storage by migrating to alternatives such as [Context#getExternalFilesDir(String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)), [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore), or [Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).

So:

- `getExternalFilesDir` returns `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mypackage/files/Download`. This path is not useful, I expected it to return `/storage/emulated/0/Download`, which is where the downloaded files are.
- I didn't manage to do something with `MediaStore.Downloads`. I checked the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#request-permissions) and it says "In particular, if your app wants to access a file within the MediaStore.Downloads collection that your app didn't create, you must use the Storage Access Framework.". So, I assume it won't work for me.
- In my concept, `Intent` and `Storage Access Framework` would need the user to navigate through directories and files using a File Manager, which is not what I want here.

**In short:**

Is it possible to list the `.txt` downloaded files **programmatically** in Android Q (SDK >= 29)? If so, how?

Comment: In Android Q you can. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60413633/cant-read-data-from-external-storage-android-emulator

Comment: `There is a share feature in my app, so I am using a FileProvider. ` That has nothing to do with your wanted access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to list the .txt downloaded files programmatically in Android Q (SDK >= 29)?

Not ones created by other apps, which would appear to be your intention.

The closest is if you use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and ask the user to open the `Downloads/` tree on external storage... and you cannot do that on Android R (at least through DP1).

Comment: I just found [this article](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html) on your blog. It's pretty elucidating about the storage subject.

Comment: What about getting the self-created files by the apps after reinstall app? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63593112/do-we-need-permission-to-get-all-files-that-is-self-created-by-the-app-after-the

Comment: is there no other way to do this nowadays? no other way than asking the use to manually open the `Downloads/` folder?

Comment: @noloman: You do not have independent access to files created by other apps in `Downloads/`, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: yes, indeed that's what I was asking: I thought the `Download` folder was an external directory where files could be stored and open, and I thought I could create an app that listed all the filese in the `Download` folder

Comment: @noloman: You are welcome to request `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, but unless you have a very good reason for it, your app may be rejected from the Play Store or other app distribution channels.